# Extjs beautiful synchronous Popup

Tags: extjs, popup

Is there a beautiful synchron Popup in extjs, to replace the standard Popup(alert("xyz")) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you really mean ‘synchronous’, or are you just using it to mean the kind of in-page pop-up element that is sometimes (misleadingly) called ‘modal’?

Because if you really need truly synchronous dialogue boxes, that return a result in the same thread of execution they were called, you only have:

- the built-in `alert()` and `confirm()` boxes;
- a seperate `showModalDialog()` window (IE extension, to be standardised by HTML5)

These are both generally undesirable because, being synchronous, they hang up the whole user interface in most browsers. `showModalDialog` is usually considered especially offensive.

You should replace them with asynchronous dialogue boxes that return results via a callback (such as the message-boxes linked by Erik), wherever possible.

Comment: for inattentive people like me - alert() and confirm() here is related to plain js, not to Ext.MessageBox

Answer (score 6):

http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/message-box/msg-box.html

I don't know about beautiful, but thats extjs's modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'alert',
    id: 'alert',
    width: 120,
    margin: '70 0 4 10',
    disabled: true,
    handler: function() {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Alert', 'xyz');
    }
}
```

This is a message box which looks much better than the general alert, you can also use `confirm()` in place of `Ext.MessageBox.alert`

**like:**

```
Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Confirm', 'xyz' , function(btn){
    if(btn === 'yes'){
        //`enter code here`
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely take a look at [Ext.window.Toast](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.window.Toast)

```
Ext.toast('Ola!! Me Toast..');
```

Here, try this fiddle - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lhk

It has more aesthetics than Alert.